# Getting BSON string from from mongoid document object

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Given an example document as below is there a way to get a bson string representing the document?

```
class Foobar
  include Mongoid::Document

  store_in collection :foobars

  field :n, as: :name, type: String
  field :ts, as: :install_timestamp, type: DateTime

end
```

ie

```
john_smith = Foobar.create(name: "John Smith", install_timestamp: Time.now)

john_smith.bson_string
```

which would return one of the following

```
{
  "n": "John Smith",
  "ts": {"$date": {"$numberLong":"1573596151000"} }
}
```

or

```
{
  "n": "John Smith",
  "ts" : ISODate("2019-11-12T22:02:31.848Z"),
}
```

I've tried doing this utilizing the underlying BSON library and the to_bson function but that returns a bytebuffer which I can't manage to get converted into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure, if this is what you need, but

```rb
class Foobar
  include Mongoid::Document

  store_in collection: :foobars

  field :n, as: :name, type: String
  field :ts, as: :install_timestamp, type: DateTime
end
```

```rb
john_smith = Foobar.create(name: "John Smith", install_timestamp: Time.now)
# => #<Foobar _id: 5dcca0b9909208042530925a, n(name): "John Smith", ts(install_timestamp): 2019-11-14 00:32:57 UTC>
```

```rb
john_smith_attributes = john_smith.attributes
# => {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5dcca0b9909208042530925a'), "n"=>"John Smith", "ts"=>2019-11-14 00:32:57 UTC}
```

```rb
bson = john_smith_attributes.to_bson
# => #<BSON::ByteBuffer:0x00007fd59d16eb10>
```

```rb
bson_string = bson.to_s
# => "4\x00\x00\x00\a_id\x00]\xCC\xA0\xB9\x90\x92\b\x04%0\x92Z\x02n\x00\v\x00\x00\x00John Smith\x00\tts\x00\xC2\xD5Sgn\x01\x00\x00\x00"
```

```rb
BSON::Document.from_bson(BSON::ByteBuffer.new(bson_string))
# => {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5dcca0b9909208042530925a'), "n"=>"John Smith", "ts"=>2019-11-14 00:32:57 UTC}
```

Links to docs:

1. [BSON::ByteBuffer#to_s](https://api.mongodb.com/bson-ruby/current/BSON/ByteBuffer.html#to_s-instance_method)
2. [from_bson and to_bson](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/tutorials/bson-v4/#ruby-bson-tutorial)
3. [attributes](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#accessing-field-values)

Hope this helps.